# Impute missing values (bmi) in Python based on means from different gender and age range

Tags: python

Suppose I have 3 columns - gender, age, and bmi

Some bmi has missing values

I have computed the mean based on different gender and age range

and now I would like to impute the missing value based on the gender and age range

Any kind assistance please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you accepted the answer, you can click on the check sign beside my answer to have it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The columns you are talking about do not seem very informative to impute the missing values accurately but, you can still simply impute using the following steps:

- Encode the column values to numerical ones like:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df = le.fit_transform(<your_dataframe_here>)
```

- Use `SimpleImputer` to impute like the following:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
df_new = imp.fit_transform(<encoded_datagrame_here>)
df_new
```